# stop ALL scheduled tasks

Tags: c#, windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks

does anyone know if there is a tool or something i can do in C# that will stop ALL scheduled tasks 
on a windows 2003 server machine?

Comment: Is a powershell script acceptable?

Comment: @conrad can it start and stop eveyrthing?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by stop? Does this mean disable the scheduled items or deleting them from scheduler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is to stop the "Task Scheduler" service.

Comment: Take care: the Task Schedular service powers some important tasks, see http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/07/15/why-you-shouldn-t-disable-the-task-scheduler-service-in-windows-7-and-windows-8.aspx

Comment: The link looks like its been changed. I think this is what Johan was previously linking: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2013/07/14/why-you-shouldnt-disable-the-task-scheduler-service-in-windows-7-and-windows-8/

Comment: @JohanvanderSlikke  -  Out of the box,  what are you saying is running with task scheduler by default ?

Answer (score 1):

With shift-click you can select multiple items, then with right mouse click you can disable all selected items at once